# How to publish SQL Server Spatial views to GeoServer?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sql-server-spatial, publishing

I have a web mapping service created on ESRI infrastructure (ArcGIS Server (WFS and WMS) with editable data from SQL Server Spatial. I am trying to switch from ArcGIS to Geoserver. I have published the layers from QGIS using [GeoServer Explorer Plugin](http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/quickstart.html#). But all the SQL Server Spatial tables are getting converted to shapefiles. The plugin allows to connect to PostGIS as in the linked page, but currently all my data is on SQL Server db and heavily related to quite a many attribute tables. Also since the web application has the editing workflow, so publishing static shapefile won't work for me. Is the way to publish views from SQL Server spatial to GeoServer is to publish views from PostGRE linked to SQL server? Are there any fallback for the approach - performance etc.? I am open to experiment with any other open source product if there is any setback for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install the [SQL Server Plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlserver.html) and then you follow the normal procedure for displaying [database views in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html).

I'm not sure if adding the plugin will enable sharing from QGIS or not, if you have Boundless support I'm sure they can tell you, otherwise feel free to experiment and report back here.

Comment: I installed the plugin and published the map service - I have not got warning (unlike last time getting converted to shapefile). It published successfully. But my attribute change in SQL Server did not reflect on map service - (checked for caching etc.). I can see the change in QGIS project.

Comment: I have posted another question related to geoserver (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184543/how-to-call-legend-end-points-of-multiple-layers-published-from-geoserver).