# How to call Legend end points of multiple layers published from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, legend, getlegendgraphic, scale-factor

I have map services published from ArcGIS server being called from Angular- Leaflet app and we are displaying the legend (controlled through map controls) from 
https://pxxxx.com/arcgis/rest/services/aaa/aaa/MapServer/Legend?f=pjson&token=ddddd.&callback=angular.callbacks._0

and receiving the Json as below based on layerID 
 `angular.callbacks._0({
 "layers": [
  {
   "layerId": 1,
   "layerName": "abc",
   "layerType": "Feature Layer",
   "minScale": 0,
   "maxScale": 0,
   "legend": [
    {
     "label": "",
     "url": "76d5be60e5691543860aa46358f5dcf8",
     "imageData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAF9JREFUOI1jYaAyYIExzFcw/EeXPBnBwEisPIaBlACYZScjGBjhBmKzjZBrsAGquBDDQGQnU8VAagKqGIjss8HpQgwDKY0MrOmQWmA0HZIH6J8OKSkbqZIOCbqQkrIRAPKcIWF3tuu1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
     "contentType": "image/png",
     "height": 20,
     "width": 20
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "layerId": 3,
   "layerName": "xyz",
   "layerType": "Feature Layer",
   "minScale": 750000,
   "maxScale": 0,
   "legend": [
    {
     "label": "",
     "url": "0c13bfd1080ed2b63ddc93e033c6739e",
     "imageData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAElJREFUOI3t1DEKACAMA8AIfi+vzQPrVEFwqpmkmTpdM2XCnAkAkuIVIjk26IikIDkOML9UsLxtDRtssMGPQccu2hoeA1vdwVsWVeQROSDODxUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
     "contentType": "image/png",
     "height": 20,
     "width": 20
    }
   ]
  },`

The most complex map service consists of 53 layers and there are some more services. We are planning to switch to geoserver. Geoserver's [getlegendgrahics](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html#get-legend-graphic) works only for one layer at one time. So almost feels like there has to be 53 + calls just to gather legend info (unless I am missing something). Also legend in current application are being displayed based on the max and min scale through map controls- which in case of geoserver are stored in SLDs- is there any workflow similar in geoserver e.g. what will be the end point to use SLD info? (it may sound as 2 questions but both are from same context and very much related.)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog](http://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/developers-corner-geoserver-getlegendgraphic-enhancements/), the `GetLegendGraphic` call will render a legend for [Layer Groups](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/layergroups.html). However, I wasn't able to confirm that in Geoserver documentation--perhaps because it's implicit that it should work? And unfortunately our Geoserver instance predates the blog (11.02.2013) so I wasn't able to test it against one of our layer groups, either. :/

If you're loading your layers individually for toggling display on/off, you might try making a layer group with a few layers just to see if you can call `GetLegendGraphic` on the group layer. Then if it works, just create a group layer with all of your layers in it for the sake of grabbing a huge legend graphic.

Comment: I looked into it. But it is returning graphics - I want JSON back. I noticed this proposed change - https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/GSIP-81---GetLegendGraphic-as-text-(JSON) but not sure which release includes this one. I installed 2.8.2(stable) and don't see any option.